# How do i delete one row in my SQLite table?

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to delete one row of data from my sql table called "cart".
It seems to me that it can not find the id called "cartid". im using a program called insomnia and it wont take my input it feels like.

it is gettting a error that is called :"MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

im using laravel 5.4, it is a requirement for me.

i have other functions that work and i do not understand why this one does not.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKikW.jpg

some snapshots from my code

i have tried to use

```
Route::delete('cart-remove/{id}', 'CartController@delete');
```

and alot more

this is in my 'api.php' file:

```
Route::delete('cart-remove', 'CartController@delete');
```

this is in my file called 'CartController':

```php
class CartController extends Controller {

    public function delete($id) {

        DB::table('cart')->where('cartid', '=', $id)->delete();

        return response($id, 200);


    }
}
```

i want to get the id from my program called 'insomnia' to remove that id in my sqlite database.

Comment: `:id` if not set wont be set into `$id`, because your using `?id=` parm etc, maybe if you want to use both your need to use `Input::get` as well, or just remove that rout which expect no `:id`. you only need `Route::delete('cart-remove', 'CartController@delete');` if you want to delete them all, else expect/handle the id

Comment: You should make your DELETE request against `/cart-remove/123`, _not_ try to send the id in the request body as you currently appear to be doing.

Comment: @misorude so should i make my delete request like i did before? with the {id} after the cart-remove/? and how should the CartController.php look then? the same?

Comment: Controller should stay the same. _Because_ you have set up your route as `cart-remove/{id}`, it will automatically pass the value from that position in the URL _as_ $id into your controler’s delete method call.

Answer (score 0):

Use the model's `destroy` method when deleting entries from the database:

```
use App\SomeModel;

class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function destroy($id) //or delete($id)
    {
         SomeModel::destroy($id);
         return response($id, 200);
    }
}
```